# Slowness in the geolocation API

Tags: geolocation, here-api

I'm working on a project that uses HERE's geolocation service.

The project is basically a feature in our system that will route a list of addresses. This routing will happen every day and will have around 7000 points, at least.

Today we use the HERE service to geolocate these addresses and send them to our routing service. However, we are facing a huge bottleneck in this implementation: Of the 7000 points we use for testing, we were able to send only about 200 to geolocate, if we send a larger number of points, we simply do not receive any more response, nor the return of timeout or anything like that.

About the implementation: we do not send all points in the same request, each point to be geocoded is sent in a request. We adjusted our software to send only four requests per second thinking that there could be a QPS block, but we were not successful in solving the problem. We thought about also implementing a massage queue, but this could end up increasing the total time of geolocation + routing, which for us makes the solution unfeasible.

In the code, we have an array that stores the addresses to be geocoded, and for each position of the array we execute a GET request for the following URL: https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=TOKEN&searchtext=ADDRESS

If you can help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using our freemium service ? just to let you know that our 6.2 version of geocoder API is no longer support any new feature development, and hence if you are still implmenting the use case. Please try to switch to V7. Do you mean that you are not able to send entire 7000 addresses and fetch response even in chunks. It could be also due to Linux system that has restricted number of pool network connections on the same moment.try to send requests from some home endpoint (that not behind firewall ) and from Windows system

Answer (score 0):

For a large numbers of geocodes you may wish to consider the Batch Geocoder API:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-batch-geocode.html

I cannot replicate a problem with more than 200 Geocoder requests in a row, so we may need to see some code before we can help further.